# Factory Design pattern in languages with class types

Tags: design-patterns

I was reading in Peter Norvig's [Design Patterns](http://www.norvig.com/design-patterns/design-patterns.pdf) presentation.  From slide 13:

> Dynamic version needs only the Window classes.
>
> The classes themselves serve as factories
>
> This works because classes are first-class values We can say `make(c)`

Does it mean that Java and C# don't need the factory design pattern since they can pass around class type as a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eh, you're missing the key part of the quote: `We can say make(c)`.

While you can pass around types in Java and C#, you can't (nicely, always) then instantiate an object from that type you're passing around. The types aren't guaranteed to be classes (rather than interfaces, enums, delegates). The types aren't guaranteed to be concrete (how do you "make" an abstract class?). The types aren't guaranteed to have default constructors.

Even then, you can always pass around a delegate that fits the right signature and will build you the correct type. That's a perfectly good approach, and a welcome change to the overuse of factories in many places.

The problem is that factories aren't often *just* some variable type to spin up. More often than not, your factory needs to get some information in order to create the right instance. And very often, the place that specifies what factory to use doesn't know that information (or else it could just create the right instance and use that).

Comment: Thanks @Telastyn , it makes sense that we will need to pass around parameters for constructor hence make(c) does not directly map in C# and Java. Can you give an example from any other language, which overcomes this shortcoming and allows to use make(c)? How do they take care of param passing?